# confliction between lineno and subfloat?

Tags: subfloats

I was using both `subfig` and `lineno` at the same time.

```
\documentclass[aapm,graphicx]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{graphicx}  
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\linenumbers\relax 

\begin{document}
```

However, when I draw the figure:

```
\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{figure5a.eps}}
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{figure5b.eps}}
\caption{  }
\label{fig5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Errors come out:

```
! Improper \prevdepth.<recently read> \prevdepth ...ludegraphics[height=2.0in]{figure5a.eps}}
! You can't use `\prevdepth' in restricted horizontal mode.
```

But if I comment out `\linenumbers\relax`, the errors go away although the line number cannot be displayed. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, your example document compiles fine when using `article` instead of `revtex4-1`, so it seems it's an incompatibility between `revtex4-1` and `lineno`, the `figure` using `floatrow` and `subfig` is just triggering the problem.

Now back to the problem itself: The `lineno` package tries hard to prevent page breaks at unwanted locations, and this code has changed over time. An excerpt from lineno.sty:

```
% (New v4.00) 
%                                                  \begin{old}\begin{verbatim}
% %          \kern\z@ 
% \end{verbatim}
%                                                                    \end{old}
% was here previously. What for? 
% According to \TeX book p._125, Stephan's 
% interline penalty is changed into 10000. At the end of a 
% paragraph, the ~\parskip~ would follow that penalty of 10000, 
% so there could be a page break neither at the 
% ~\parskip~ nor at the ~\baselineskip~ (\TeX book p._110)---so 
% there could never be a page break between two paragraphs. 
% So something must screen off the 10000 penalty. 
% Indeed, the ~\kern~ is a place to break. 
% (Stephan once knew this: see `allow pagebreaks' above.)
% 
% Formerly, I tried to replace ~\kern\z@~ by 
%                                                  \begin{old}\begin{verbatim}
% %         \penalty\@LN@parpgpen\relax 
% \end{verbatim}
%                                                                    \end{old}
% ---but this allows a page break after heading. So: 
%% 
      \@LN@parpgbrk 
%% 
%% After heading, ~\kern\z@~ resulting from previous line 
%% (see below) is followed by ~\write~ or ~\penalty10000~, 
%% so causes no page break. 
% 
% These and similar changes were formerly done by ~linenox1.sty~. 
% (/New v4.00)
```

`\@LN@parpgbrk` is defined as:

```
% (New v4.00, v4.4) Initialize ~\@LN@parpgbrk~, accounting 
% for earlier space and for appropriate columndepth. 
% We use former ~\MakeLineNo~'s depth-preverving trick 
% ~\@LN@depthbox~ again: 

\def\@LN@screenoff@pen{% 
  \ifdim\lastskip=\z@ 
    \@tempdima\prevdepth \setbox\@tempboxa\null 
    \@LN@depthbox                           \fi}

\global\let\@LN@parpgbrk\@LN@screenoff@pen 

% (/New v4.4, v4.00)
```

This code is faulty. It assumes that it's in vertical mode always, using `\prevdepth` without extra check.

Since I don't have enough inside into the code of `lineno` to offer a bullet-proof fix (Is adding `\ifvmode`..`\fi` sufficient?), I suggest simply reverting `\@LN@parpgbrk` back to `\penalty\@LN@parpgpen\relax`, so we have at least a workaround for your problem:

```
\documentclass[aapm,graphicx]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}  
\usepackage[caption=false, font=footnotesize]{subfig}
\usepackage{floatrow}

\usepackage[mathlines]{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\linenumbers\relax 

% Workaround for problem in lineno.sty
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\linenumberpar{\@LN@parpgbrk}{\penalty\@LN@parpgpen\relax}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\floatsetup[figure]{style=plain,subcapbesideposition=top}
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{figure5a.eps}}%
\sidesubfloat[]{\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{figure5b.eps}}%
\caption{  }
\label{fig5}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

I suggest sending the maintainer of the `lineno` package a bug report and trying using the above workaround until the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

When using `\linenumbers\relax` in `{revtex4-1}`, I got a similar error

> ```
> ! Improper \prevdepth.<recently read> \prevdepth \begin{document}.
> ```

By moving the `\linenumbers\relax` inside `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, this error is solved!